# finding next sibling in a jquery accordian menu

Tags: jquery-selectors

So, my problem is that I can't seem to find the next() sibling down to the following nested ul li. when set to hide. I can find it when it's not set to hide easily by:

- This works when I comment out the JS and nothing is hidden: 
  //$(".vertNavigation li ul a").hide();
- Add this to click function: 
  $(this).next().css("background", "yellow").slideToggle("normal");

Goal is to do the reverse, click on BUTTON ONE and slideDown nested ul and so on. What is it that I'm missing here?

HTML CODE:

```
</head>

<body>
<div class = "vertNavigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id = "button One">BUTTON ONE</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 1</a>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 2</a>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 3</a>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 4</a>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id = "button Two">BUTTON TWO</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 1</a>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 2</a>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 3</a>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 4</a>
            </ul>
        </li>    
        <li><a href="#" id = "button Two">BUTTON THREE</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 1</a>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 2</a>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 3</a>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 4</a>
            </ul>        
        </li>    
        <li><a href="#" id = "button Two">BUTTON FOUR</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 1</a>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 2</a>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 3</a>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 4</a>
            </ul>        
        </li>    
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.vertNavigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-lef: 0;
}

.vertNavigation li {
    display: inline;
}

.vertNavigation a { /*main menu*/
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
    padding: 6px 15px 3px 15px;
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
    color: #333;

    font-size: .8em;
}

.vertNavigation li ul a {  /*sub menu*/
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #333;
    border-length: 50px;
    margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #333;
}
```

JS CODE:

```
google.load("jquery", "1.6.2");

google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){

    $(".vertNavigation li ul a").hide();
    $(".vertNavigation ul li a").click(function()
    {
        //$(this).next().slideToggle("normal");
        $(this).next().slideDown("normal");

        return false;   
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".vertNavigation > ul > li > ul").hide();
$(".vertNavigation > ul > li > a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

[Check the live working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/HdjfY/)

Comment: Shef, Thanks! You answered my question, but preventDefault() won't allow me to link a URL, correct?

Comment: *(pressed return by accident)...*  I like what you've shown me. You are bubbling back to register the click, and you also rearranged my hide() targeting. As you can tell I'm new to jQuery.

Comment: @milkIt: The accordions themselves won't be able to link somewhere, otherwise the accordion functionality would not work, because when you click a link by the time you expect the sub `ul` to show, the link will have taken you somewhere else. Use the updated code to be 100% sure the links on the sub `ul`s will work. :)

Comment: Again, Thanks! I like what you've written.  I'm trying other possibilities just to learn more and I realized that my hide() targeting had a huge effect on my outcome. I deleted the a in hide() and slideToggle() works.  $(".vertNavigation li ul").hide();
 $(".vertNavigation ul li a").click(function()
 {
  $(this).next().css("background", "yellow").slideToggle("normal");
  
 });

});

Comment: I noticed that placing the > in between the ul made the difference on being able to link url. Why is that? Is it shorthand?...

Comment: @milklt: Placing the `>` means select the direct child element, and not other inner children. Read [Descendant Selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) vs [Child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) for a much more detailed explanation.

Comment: Made changes cause I wanted to make the accordion expand only one ul at a time. So I tried an if/esle statement, bind/unbind, finally I came across this: [link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1827-Using-jQuery-s-SlideUp-and-SlideDown-Methods-With-Bottom-Positioned-Elements.htm)  Based on Shef's code, I Finally figured this out. Copy and paste this in the click function block: event.preventDefault();
 // collapse all open sub heading lists    $(".vertNavigation ul li ul").slideUp();    // expand next list, stop() to prevent animation Queu Buildup    $(this).next("ul").stop().slideDown("normal")